# Where is the icon path of an icon in Visual Studio's Windows Style

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, icons

I created long time ago a C# WinForm application and I added some icon in the Window Style's icon field:
[image: al]

I can't find this icon so I thought the path will appear in Visual Studio but I can't find it.

How can I find the icon's path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon is stored in the resource file of the form. If for any reason you need the file, you can export it from the resource file:

1. Double click on Form1.resx file in Solution Explorer
2. In the resource designer, click on drop down of the first button of the toolbar and choose Icons.
3. In the list view, you will see the icon.
4. Rich click on the icon and click Export to file and save it wherever you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick look inside Form Designer tells me this:

```
 this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

Meaning it is stored as a resource in Systems.Windows.Forms.dll assembly.

There is no direct path but I saw [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174604/where-to-find-the-default-winforms-icon-in-windows) to a similar question which gives instructions on how to get a copy, although I haven't personally tested any of them.