# Default Icon Missing in VS2022, showing in VS2019

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

After upgrading the code from .NET core3.1 to .NET6, and after starting using the VS2022 from VS2019, I am not able to see the default WinForms icon for my windows application.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I tried looking for the icon properties for the project but could not find the default icon option in VS2022, which I can see in VS2019.

Comment: It's in the Application -> Win32 Resources section of the Project's properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to find the default Winforms icon in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174604/where-to-find-the-default-winforms-icon-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can search for properties:

[image]

Select the `icon` in the categorized:

[image]

The second method:
`project`->`properties`->`Applications`->`win32 resources`

[image]

Update：

You could use this to get it.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Icon icon = this.Icon;
            Stream output = new FileStream("saved_icon.ico", FileMode.Create);
            icon.Save(output);
            output.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The icon which you see in the first method is black and white with three linked boxes and I think you have opened it in VS2022, but when you will open that in VS2019, you will be able to find the coloured version of the icon with three colours in those three boxes. So i want that same icon in my VS2022 too. How can i get that? Could you please help.

Comment: The colored version you mentioned is the default icon under the .net framework. If you want to use the default icon of .NET Framework, you can create a .net framework Winform and download an icon yourself, and then use it. I have updated my answer, you can mark it if it is useful.